# Differential gain of op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential-amplifier

So I was reading the chapter on Op Amps in Microelectronic circuits by Sedra, Smith, the topic on Differential Amplifiers to be exact.

Here's the amplifier: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qWzi.png

To get this to behave as a differential amplifier, it had been proved that R1/R2 = R3/ R4, and the using this condition, the final gain turns our to be R2/R1.

That seemed simple enough, but I didn't get the following statement:

> Note that if the amplifier is required to have a large differential gain, then R1 of
> necessity will be relatively small and the input resistance will be correspondingly low, a
> drawback of this circuit. Another drawback of the circuit is that it is not easy to vary the differential
> gain of the amplifier. Both of these drawbacks are overcome in the instrumentation
> amplifier discussed next.

Here, what exactly do they mean by "it is not easy to vary the differential gain of the amplifier"? It's just R2/R1, so that should be easy enough to manipulate, right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the input resistance of this 1-opamp differential amplidier, it is not the same for both circuit inputs. It is equal to R1 for the inverting input and it is R3 + R4 for the non-inverting input. You can make both input resistances high and equal... and also to adust the gain only by one resistor with a 3-opamp circuit of a more sophisticated differential amplifier known as "instrumentation amplifier".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *what exactly do they mean by "it is not easy to vary the differential
> gain of the amplifier"*

They mean that if you want to change the gain on-the-fly then you have to adjust R1 and R3 simultaneously and that's a lot of bother. The InAmp only has one gain set resistor and is easily changed and doesn't screw with common-mode rejection either.

[image]